# Azure Cognitive Search : Sort result by particular result String

Tags: javascript, azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way in azure search, to bring data `orderby` value to top and remaining below. Bringing the hotel's in user's location country to top and then other results

For example:
See the sample data below

| HotelName | City | Country | RoomType | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | City1 | **India** | abc | 4 |
| UVW | City2 | Australia | def | 5 |
| KWHK | City3 | India | 6 |  |
| KHUK | City4 | China | 2 |  |

I want to get all the data, but country `India` should be at top result and remaining should be below. (which includes pagination).

I am doing  lucene query POST search for same , and below is my query json body for same .

`Query: { search: *, queryType: 'full', count: true, skip: 0, top: 10, scoringStatistics: 'global', searchMode: 'any', }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you include the country in your search should work, for example:

```
search=term OR (term and Country eq 'India')
```

a Similar question was answered by a MSFT product manager with more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44766731/1384539

Comment: Add below query but still search gives random result   "search": "/.*/ || (/.*/ && country eq 'INDIA')"

Comment: try to search for a particular word first and see if you get the expected results

Comment: when you use * as your search term, it will match all the docs. The boolean query won't work for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the geo.distance function in Search, basically when querying, you need to pass the current user's location as a edm.GeographyPoint in the Function, then when ordering the results, you can order them by closest to fartest location from the user.
Documentation on this, there you will also see some examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-geo-spatial-functions

```
POST /indexes/hotels/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30
    {  
      "search": "*",  
      "orderby": "geo.distance(Location, geography'POINT(-122.12315 47.88121)')"
    }
```